# How to fix memcpy.asm error when assigning a value to an std::string through a pointer?

Tags: c++

I made this code for a Stack struct:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
template<uint32_t S>
struct Stack {
    size_t size;
    byte base[S];
    byte* top;
    //
    Stack()
    {
        top = (byte*)base;
        size = 0;
    }
    ~Stack(){}
    //
    template<class T>
    void alloc(T*& rt)
    {
        if (sizeof(T) > MAXBYTE) return;
        rt = (T*)top;
        top += sizeof(T);
        size += sizeof(T) + 1;
        *top = sizeof(T);
        top++;
    }
    void alloc(void*& rt, size_t arg)
    {
        if (arg > MAXBYTE) return;
        rt = top;
        top += arg;
        size += arg + 1;
        *top = arg;
        top++;
    }
    template<class T>
    void* push(T arg)
    {
        if (arg > MAXBYTE) return 0;
        T* rt;
        alloc<T>(rt);
        *rt = arg;
        return rt;
    }
    template<class T>
    T&& pop()
    {
        if (top == base) return 0;
        top--;
        size -= *top;
        top -= *top;
        return (T&&)*(T*)top;
    }
    void pop()
    {
        if (top == base) return;
        top--;
        size -= *top;
        top -= *top;
    }
};
```

it works perfectly well when i play around with primitive values and custom structs, but throws a peculiar error if i use an std::string

```cpp
int main()
{
    Stack<64> t;
    std::string* a;
    t.alloc(a);
    *a = "TEST";
    //
    std::cout << "press enter to exit...";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

the error says "access violation reading location", occurs in memcpy.asm and MSVS2019 always says it occurs one "functional" (meaning non-whitespace and non-comment) line after the assignment.
When i do sizeof(std::string) it tells me it's 28, so a 64-byte Stack should have no problem containing that, even with an additional byte carrying its size at the end.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can't just point a `std::string` pointer as some random memory and expect it to work. You need to construct an actual object. You could use placement new for this or you could just throw the whole idea out the window and do it the proper way.

Comment: `*a = "TEST";` -- There is no `std::string` object created.  C++ is not C.  C++ requires you to actually create objects.  It's equivalent to me giving you a bunch of nuts and bolts, some wires, coolant, and tell you it's an air conditioner and can just plug it in to see it "work".

Comment: The placement new solves the problem, thanks. Yet again, this code still works when I use a struct like {int a; float b;}, I can assign a value to it and read it without first initializing it with any form of construction, which would contradict the idea that a construction is needed. I suppose it's an object-specific thing and it just so happens that std::string needs construction (as would some other classes) because it uses its properties before any assignment. Is that correct?

Comment: @nikodem0808 *but throws a peculiar error if i use an std::string* -- It is not just `std::string`.  Any type where [std::is_standard_layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) returns false will have the same issue.

Comment: @nikodem0808 -- *I suppose it's an object-specific thing and it just so happens that std::string needs construction* -- The bottom line is that the C++ compiler will only see `n` bytes, and not know any idea it is a `std::string` a `std::vector`, or a `Widget` class you came up with.  Thus calling member functions and pretending those `n` bytes are some object will not work.  The compiler has to be told that yes, those bytes mean that this is an object of type `T`.  The `placement-new` does just this.

Comment: Well, I thought  that dereferencing an ```std::string*``` would make the compiler think the bytes make up an ```std::string```, so that is confusing, but the ```std::is_standard_layout``` thing seems to be a fitting suspect here. Thanks again for the help.
And one last question, is this kind of post something I should remove after getting an answer, or should I let it stay? It feels like there are many questions like it, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem before.

Comment: Precisely. Dereferencing an `std::string*` does make the compiler think that the bytes make up an `std::string` - but in your program, the bytes do **not** in fact make up a valid `std::string`. You are lying to the compiler, and your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Other things that are broken, just of the top of my head: Alignment is completely disregarded, the `delete[]` is wrong, and in fact the cleanup code is impossible to write correctly without additional type information or manual handling (e.g., when popping, the object is not actually destructed).

Comment: @danielschemmel Sorry about that, I updated the code to actually allocate on the stack (earlier I used new ```byte[S]```) and forgot to remove ```delete[]```. As for alignment and cleanup, this particular struct was meant to just give the bytes to whomever asks, no strings attached, and all the rest must be handled by the receiving side. Yet this brings up another question: would abandoning the address (user-side) without calling the destructor still work if the object has no memory allocated on the heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments note: you need to create a string in order to assign a value to it.

C++ has construction and assignment, and the two are fundamentally different. Construction is done via the constructor, and creates an object out of raw memory. Assignment is done via the `operator=` member function, and like all operators requires that an object already exists.

Now most of the times you don't need to do much work to call a constructor. Just write ``string s { "This is the initial value"];` in any function, and you construct a local variable. It will be destructed automatically when the function returns.

There are many more ways in which you can create objects. Adding an element to a container, for instance, or calling `std::make_unique`.

In your case, you're implementing your own container. That means it's now up to you to call the primitive functions. You could use the new `std::construct_at`, or the old *placement new.* . And obviously, call `std::destruct_at` when popping an element.